# Does install4j provide a *Completely* unattended auto update?

Tags: install4j

We are currently evaluating install4j and things are going pretty well, however I have a question about auto-update.
Currently I see options and documentation around 3 options for auto-update and the third one (no version check) seems
to be the closest to what we need.  However it sounds as though it still prompts the user to actually start the download/install.  Is there
any way to get around this?  We are targeting our software as a service on many windows boxes in a server room, so there isn't a user
to click continue for that last step.  I believe we can roll our own service to monitor for upgrades that will do a command line
install with an answers file to prevent prompting, but I'd love to know if I missed something that would allow me to utilize
install4j's auto-update.

Answer (score 2):

When you go to Installer->Screens & Actions, click on the "Add" button and choose "Add application", you can choose from a number of pre-defined templates. However, they are just templates and after adding them you can change them completely.

If the updater should be automatic but still show a progress dialog, you can just set the "Default execution mode" property of the updater application to "Unattended mode with progress dialog". In that case, no screens will be shown at all.

[image]